# Evitar rellamada a un Listener

Tags: javafx

Estoy detectando el cambio de valor de un grupo de botones con un `Listener`. Si no hay nada seleccionado coloco el valor anterior antes del cambio, pero esto me provoca una rellamada al `Listener` ¿Cómo puedo evitarlo?

El código es:

```
toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(
    (ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> arg0, Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) -> {
        if (toggleGroup.getToggles().indexOf(toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle()) == -1) {                
                    toggleGroup.selectToggle(oldValue); // esto provoca rellamada al Listener
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Comprueba si `oldValue` es igual a `newValue` y en ese caso no asignes nada :) Así aun que te vuelva a llamar no lo cambiará y no volverá a llamar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un flag que indique si has intentado anular todas las opciones del `toggleGroup`:

```
boolean flag = false; // variable gobal

toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(
(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> arg0, Toggle viejo, Toggle nuevo) -> {            

    if (flag){              
        flag = false;
        return;
    }           

    if (nuevo == null){                                                   
        flag = true;               
        toggleGroup.selectToggle(viejo);
        return;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: lo que describo más abajo después de la línea parece incorrecto. pongo otra respuesta.

Si guardas en una variable global el valor que estas asignando puedes evitar una segunda llamada:

```
String newValueAux = "";

toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(
(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> arg0, Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) -> {
    if (toggleGroup.getToggles().indexOf(toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle()) == -1) {                
                if (oldValue != newValueAux) {
                     newValueAux = oldValue;
                     toggleGroup.selectToggle(oldValue);
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

---

---

Desconozco la manera de evitar la rellamada al listener al estar en su propia declaración, pero puedes finalizar esta recursividad con una condición base.

Si `oldValue = newValue` entonces no cambies nada y el `listener` no se lanzará:

```
toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(
(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> arg0, Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) -> {
    if (toggleGroup.getToggles().indexOf(toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle()) == -1) {                
                if (oldValue != newValue) toggleGroup.selectToggle(oldValue);
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Por pura lógica, el listener sólo es llamado cuando hay un cambio de valor así que oldValue siempre será distinto a newValue.

Comment: Tienes razón, disculpáme @Oundroni. Y guardar una variable global con el último valor asignado?